# .onkey() in turtle, Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How I understand it:

In while loop I upgrade window with each iteration, then I call _snake_move() which checks if there was a button pressed (at the beginning direction is 'stop', so nothing happens), then if 'w' is pressed then go_up() is called which changes snake.direction to 'up'. With next iteration of the loop we call _snake_move() which now activates one of the conditional statements and causes sety(y+20) which should move the snake. Why it's not working?

```
import turtle


class Settings():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        """ Initialize settings of the game. """
        
        self.window_width = 500
        self.window_height = 500
        self.bgcolor = 'blue'
        self.game_title = 'Reinforced Snake'
        
        self.food = False
        
        self.snake_color = 'red'
        
        
class Reinforced_Snake():
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        """ Initialize classes for the main one. """
        
        # initialize classes
        self.settings = Settings()
        
        # initialize the main screen of the game
        self.window = turtle.Screen()
        
        self.window.bgcolor(self.settings.bgcolor)
        self.window.title(self.settings.game_title)
        self.window.setup(width = self.settings.window_width, 
                     height = self.settings.window_height)
        
        # initialize the snake
        self._init_snake()
        
        # turn off screen updates
        self.window.tracer(0)
        
    def _init_snake(self):
        
        
        """ Initialize the snake instead of creating another class. """
        
        self.snake = turtle.Turtle()
        self.snake.speed(0)
        self.snake.color(self.settings.snake_color)
        
        # so that path is not drawn
        self.snake.penup()
        
        # place the snake and freeze it initially
        self.snake.goto(0, 100)
        self.snake.direction = 'stop'
        
        
        
    def main(self):
        
        """ Main loop. """
        
        while True:
            
            self.window.update()
            self._snake_move()


    def _snake_move(self):
        
        """ Move the snake. """
        
        self.window.listen()
        
        
        self.window.onkey(self.go_up(), "w")
        
        self.window.onkey(self.go_down(), "s")
        
        self.window.onkey(self.go_right(), "d")
        
        self.window.onkey(self.go_left(), "a")
        
        
        if self.snake.direction == "up":
            y = self.snake.ycor() #y coordinate of the turtle
            self.snake.sety(20)
     
        if self.snake.direction == "down":
            y = self.snake.ycor() #y coordinate of the turtle
            self.snake.sety(-20)
     
        if self.snake.direction == "right":
            x = self.snake.xcor() #y coordinate of the turtle
            self.snake.setx(20)
     
        if self.snake.direction == "left":
            x = self.snake.xcor() #y coordinate of the turtle
            self.snake.setx(-20)
        
            
    def go_up(self):
        if self.snake.direction != "down":
            self.snake.direction = "up"
     
    def go_down(self):
        if self.snake.direction != "up":
            self.snake.direction = "down"
     
    def go_right(self):
        if self.snake.direction != "left":
            self.snake.direction = "right"
     
    def go_left(self):
        if self.snake.direction != "right":
            self.snake.direction = "left"
                
            
    
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    snake = Reinforced_Snake()
    snake.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass to onkey a function, not to call it, so remove the () brackets, like this :

```
self.window.onkey(self.go_up, "w")

self.window.onkey(self.go_down, "s")

self.window.onkey(self.go_right, "d")

self.window.onkey(self.go_left, "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should put `onkey` or also `onclick` in functions. When I tried this with my game, an error always pops up.